# Trying to get property of non-object - Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, object

I'm trying to echo out the name of the user in my article and I'm getting the

> ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object

My code:

**Models**

```
1. News

    class News extends Model
    {
      public function postedBy()
      {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
      }
      protected $table = 'news';
      protected $fillable = ['newsContent', 'newsTitle', 'postedBy'];
    }

2. User

    class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                AuthorizableContract,
                                CanResetPasswordContract
    {
        use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

        protected $table = 'users';

        protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

        protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    }
```

**Schema**

table `users`

[image]

table `news`

[image]

**Controller**

```
public function showArticle($slug)
    {
        $article = News::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
        return view('article', compact('article'));
    }
```

**Blade**

```
{{ $article->postedBy->name }}
```

When I try to remove the name in the blade `{{ $article->postedBy }}` it outputs the `id`, but when I try to add the ->name there it says `Trying to get property of non-object but I have a field` name`in my table and a`User` model. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you `print_r($article);`?

Comment: @aldrin27 print_r directly in my controller? well actually everything works, I get every field but I can't get the relation. It gives me the error

Comment: You need to foreach that inside your blade.

Comment: @aldrin27 even if I use foreach I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Do you have pivot table?

Comment: I only have 3 tables @aldrin27 in my database and that's users, news and migrations.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Is your query returning array or object? If you dump it out, you might find that it's an array and all you need is an array access ([]) instead of an object access (->).

Comment: what if i want to use `$article->poster-name` instead of `$article->poster['name']`

Comment: just cast it to object on the article model.
ex: $casts = ['poster' => 'object']

Answer (score 35):

I got it working by using [Jimmy Zoto's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32469709/4698790) answer and adding a second parameter to my `belongsTo`. Here it is:

First, as suggested by Jimmy Zoto, my code in blade
from

```
$article->poster->name
```

to

```
$article->poster['name']
```

Next is to add a second parameter in my `belongsTo`,
from

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
```

to

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
```

in which `user_id` is my foreign key in the news table.

Comment: you should also check if there is an entry in the table with `isset()`

Answer (score 30):

If you working with or loops (`for`, `foreach`, etc.) or relationships (`one to many`, `many to many`, etc.), this may mean that one of the queries is returning a `null` variable or a `null` relationship member.

**For example**: In a table, you may want to list `users` with their `roles`.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Role</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->role->name }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

**In the above case**, you may receive this error if there is even one User who does not have a Role. You should replace `{{ $user->role->name }}` with `{{ !empty($user->role) ? $user->role->name:'' }}`, like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Role</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ !empty($user->role) ? $user->role->name:'' }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

**Edit**:
You can use Laravel's the `optional` method to avoid errors ([more information](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-optional)). For example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Role</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ optional($user->role)->name }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

If you are using PHP 8, you can use the `null safe operator`:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Role</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $user?->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user?->role?->name }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: what if I don't want to use if at the blade? is there a better method out there?

Comment: You can choose arrays instead of collections.

Comment: @AliLashini You can use Null Coalescing Operator (Required PHP 7.0). `$user->role->name ?? 'No Role'`. It will print user's role name or 'No Role' when user doesn't has role relationship. It's same as `isset($user->role->name) ? $user->role->name : 'No Role'`.

Answer (score 9):

I implemented a `hasOne` relation in my parent class, defined both the foreign and local key, it returned an object but the columns of the child must be accessed as an array.
i.e. `$parent->child['column']`
Kind of confusing.

Answer (score 5):

**REASON WHY THIS HAPPENS (EXPLANATION)**

suppose we have 2 tables **users** and **subscription**.

1 user has 1 subscription

IN USER MODEL, we have

```
public function subscription()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Subscription','user_id');
}
```

we can access subscription details as follows

```
$users = User:all();

foreach($users as $user){
    echo $user->subscription;
}
```

***if any of the user does not have a subscription, which can be a case.
we cannot use arrow function further after subscription like below***

```
$user->subscription->abc   [this will not work] 
$user->subscription['abc']  [this will work]
```

***but if the user has a subscription***

```
$user->subscription->abc   [this will work]
```

**NOTE: try putting a if condition like this**

```
if($user->subscription){
 return $user->subscription->abc;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It happen that after some time we need to run

```
 'php artisan passport:install --force
```

again to generate a key this solved my problem ,

Answer (score 4):

I had also this problem. Add code like below in the related controller (e.g. UserController)

```
$users = User::all();
return view('mytemplate.home.homeContent')->with('users',$users);
```

Answer (score 4):

Laravel optional() Helper is comes to solve this problem.
Try this helper so that if any key have not value  then it not return error

```
foreach ($sample_arr as $key => $value) {        
      $sample_data[] = array(       
        'client_phone' =>optional($users)->phone        
      );
    }
 print_r($sample_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me:

```
{{ !empty($user->role) ? $user->role->name:'' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue in older PHP versions.

However, switching to **PHP version >=8.1** helped me resolve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

In my case the problem was in wrong column's naming:

In model **Product** I've tried to access **category** relationship instance to get it's name, but both column name and relationship had the same name:
***category***
instead of:

**category_id** - for column name

**category** - for relationship

Setting up key name in relationship definition like

```
public function category():hasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::class,'category');
}
```

didn't help because as soon as Laravel found property named ***category*** gave up on looking for relationship etc.

Solution was to either:

- change property name (in model and database) **or**
- change relationship name (Eg. productCategory )

Answer (score -1):

It wasn't an error in my case. However, this happened to me when I was trying to open users.index, because while testing I've deleted some data from the 'STUDENTS' table and in the 'USERS' table, a foreign key ('student_id') represents the 'STUDENTS' table. So, now when the system tries to access the 'USERS' table in which foreign key ('student_id') is null since the value got deleted from the 'STUDENTS' table.

After checking for hours when I realise this, I insert the same data again in the 'STUDENTS' table and this resolved the issue.