# Display name of select form rather than it's Id (error:Trying to get property of non-object) laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 tables tn_client and tn_project, which project have 1 client while client can have many projects, rather than displaying client id on my table, i want display its client name but when i did that its said trying to get property of non-object.

> Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PKL\netxcel-activityreport-11b90b878d39\resources\views\project.blade.php)

Above is the full error that i get, and below is the tables

> **tn_project**

[image]

> **tn_client**

[image]

> **CONTROLLER**

```
public function index(){
    Log::info('Entering index');
    return view('project')
    ->with('title','Project')
    ->with('projects',Project::with('client','invoice')->get())
    ->with('clients',Client::all())
    ->with('invoices', Invoice::all());
}

//get all data
public function getAll(){
    return Response::json(
            array(
                    'content' => Project::with('client','invoice')->get(),
                    'status' => 'success',
                )
        );
}
public function createOrEdit(){
    $currentUsername = Auth::user()->name;

    $isUpdate = false;
    $projectId = Input::get('prevId');

    //populate data
    $project = new Project;
    if($projectId != ""){
        $project = Project::where('cv_id','=',$projectId)->firstOrFail();
        $project->cv_updated_by = $currentUsername;
        $project->cn_updated_at = Carbon::now();
        $isUpdate = true;
    } else{
        $project->cv_created_by = $currentUsername;
        $project->cn_created_at = Carbon::now();
    }

    $project->cv_id = Input::get('projectId');
    $project->cv_name = Input::get('projectName');
    $project->cv_client_id = Input::get('clientId');
    $project->cn_invoice_method = Input::get('invoiceId');
    $project->cn_project_rate = Input::get('projectRate');
    $project->cn_note = Input::get('note');

    //execute
    if($isUpdate){
        Log::info("entering update mode");
        Project::where('cv_id','=',$projectId)->update(['cv_id'=>$project->cv_id,
                    'cv_name'=>$project->cv_name,
                    'cv_client_id'=>$project->cv_client_id,
                    'cn_invoice_method'=>$project->cn_invoice_method,
                    'cn_project_rate'=>$project->cn_project_rate,
                    'cn_note'=>$project->cn_note,
                    'cn_updated_at'=>$project->cn_updated_at,
                    'cv_updated_by'=>$project->cv_updated_by]);
    }else{
        $project->save();
    }

    return Response::json(
            array(
                    'content' => Project::with('client','invoice')->get(),
                    'status' => 'success',
                )
        );
}
```

> **Model**

**PROJECT**

```
<?php 
namespace Activity;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model {
    protected $table = 'tn_project';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
       'cv_id',
       'cv_name',
       'cv_client_id',
       'cn_invoice_method',
       'cn_project_rate',
       'cn_note',
       'cn_created_at',
       'cv_created_by',
       'cn_updated_at',
       'cv_updated_by'
    ];

    public function client(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Activity\Client','cv_client_id','cn_id');
    }

    public function invoice(){
        return $this->hasOne('Activity\Invoice','cn_id','cn_invoice_method');
   }
}
```

**CLIENT**

```
<?php 
namespace Activity;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model {

   protected $table = 'tn_client';
   public $timestamps = false;

   protected $fillable = [
        'cv_name',
        'cv_contact',
        'cv_email',
        'cv_phone',
        'cv_address',
        'cn_created_at',
        'cn_created_by',
        'cn_updated_at',
        'cn_updated_by'
   ];

   public function project(){
       return $this->hasOne('Activity\Project', 'cv_id', 'cn_id');
   }
}
```

> **VIEW**

this is my select form

```
<div class="col-md-9">
     <select name="clientId" id="clientId" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Client">   
         @foreach ($clients as $client) 
              <option value='{{$client->cn_id}}'>{{$client->cv_name}}</option>; 
        @endforeach     
     </select>
 </div>
```

This is how i called the function to display it in my view

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td>{{$project->cv_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$project->cv_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$project->client->cv_name}}</td><!--This is what cause an -->
        <td>{{$project->cn_invoice_method}}</td>
        <td>{{$project->cn_project_rate}}</td>
        <td>{{$project->cn_note}}</td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-success" title="edit" data-id={{$project->cv_id}} data-action="project-edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" title="delete" data-id={{$project->cv_id}} data-action="project-delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

im still new to laravel, and what did i do wrong that make such an error like that?

Comment: What's the method in the controller that returns that view with projects? Check your project relationship in the Client model. I think it should be a hasMany instead of hasOne. You should name it projects.

Comment: i thinks client model nothing to do with it since model using `project.php`, controller using `ProjectController.php`, and view using `project.blade.php`, i just still don't get how to use relationship, and btw look at my controller once again, i added some code maybe it would help

Comment: Thanks for updating the question! When you try to get data from a belongsTo relationship, it returns null if it can't find a related object. So, check if you have any projects with no client_id. If your business rules doesn't allow a project with no client, you should validate the data before creating the entry. If otherwise you can have a project with no client_id, you should do a simple check in the foreach: if($project->client){ $project->client->cv_name }

Comment: well thanks for the reference, ur comment and link in my answer both did a great job to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, i got the reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469542/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-laravel-5) so based on that reference and the basic of x->y->z, we got to check first that x->y have some value in it if yes we got to check whether it's an object or just an array, in my case it was an array so rather doing something like this

```
{{$project->client->cv_name}}
```

which is that how to display an object, we should do something like this

```
{{$project->client['cv_name']}}
```

and that is how you solve your problem, cheers :D