# Facing Errors in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am creating admin panel. When user update their profile its `userid` read by update controller method using route name `update`. The update controller method returns a view `updatedata` along with an array. I am using ORM DATABASE

**Controller**

```
public function update($id)
{
   $records = Register::find($id);
   return view('updatedata',['records' => $records]);  
}
```

**Template**

```
@extends('layout/master')
@section('content')
<h1 align="center">

@foreach($records as $records)
{!!  Form::open(['route'=>'f.update'])   !!}
<table border="2" align="center">
  <tr>
     <td>{!! Form::label('name','Name') !!}</td>
       <td>{!!  Form::text('name',$records->name) !!}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>{!!Form::label('phone','Phone')!!}</td>
       <td>{!! Form::text('phone',$records->phone) !!}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>{!! Form::label('email','E-mail') !!}</td>
       <td>{!! Form::email('email',$records->name) !!}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>{!! Form::label('course','Course') !!}</td>
       <td>{!! Form::select('course',['MCA'=>'MCA','BTECH'=>'BTECH','BCA'=>'BCA'],$records->course)                                               !!}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>{!! Form::label('address','Address') !!}</td>
       <td>{!! Form::textarea('address', $records->address, ['size' => '30x3']) !!}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        {!! Form::hidden('id',$records->id) !!}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2" align="center">{!!  Form::submit() !!}</td>
    </tr>

</table>

{!!  Form::close()                                    !!}
@endforeach 
</h1>
@endsection
```

**Error**

> 2/2
>   ErrorException in 4de1c6468785010f583b37a90fa7bed16c4e92a7.php line 10:
>   Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\updatedata.blade.php)

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to get property of non-object - Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469542/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-laravel-5)

Comment: You should read about how to ask questions on Stackoverflow, `hello to all, I am new in laravel framework` doesn't make sense at all...

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `find` Eloquent method, it will return you `one` model.

```
$record = Register::find($id);
```

If you want multiple models, you'd need to use the `get` method instead. For example:

```
$records = Register::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();
```

In your view, you're trying to use a `foreach` loop to iterate over a collection of models. However you have only one.

```
// controller
public function update($id)
{
    $record = Register::findOrFail($id);
    return view('updatedata', compact('record'));  
}

// view
@extends('layout/master')

@section('content')
    {!!  Form::open(['route' => ['f.update', $record->id]])   !!}
        <table border="2" align="center">
          <tr>
             <td>{!! Form::label('name','Name') !!}</td>
               <td>{!!  Form::text('name', $record->name) !!}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>{!!Form::label('phone','Phone')!!}</td>
               <td>{!! Form::text('phone', $record->phone) !!}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>{!! Form::label('email','E-mail') !!}</td>
               <td>{!! Form::email('email', $record->name) !!}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>{!! Form::label('course','Course') !!}</td>
               <td>{!! Form::select('course', ['MCA'=>'MCA','BTECH'=>'BTECH','BCA'=>'BCA'], $record->course) !!}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>{!! Form::label('address','Address') !!}</td>
               <td>{!! Form::textarea('address', $record->address, ['size' => '30x3']) !!}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">
                {!! Form::hidden('id', $record->id) !!}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="2" align="center">{!!  Form::submit() !!}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    {!!  Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

Lastly, it's not good practice to wrap a `<form>` inside a `<h1>` element.