# Laravel 5.2 Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am following tutorial to make blog project on laravel 5.2, i am trying to show the user name from other table (users table). The post properties is shown successfully in the view, but i got Trying to get property of non-object when i try to access property from uses table.

Here is my view:

```
 <div class="blog-post">
            <h2 class="blog-post-title">
            <a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}">
            {{ $post->title }}
            </a>
            </h2>
            <p class="blog-post-meta">
            {{ $post->user->name }}
            {{ $post->created_at->toFormattedDateString() }}
            </p>

            {{ $post->body }}

          </div><!-- /.blog-post -->
```

and here is my postscontroller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\User;

use App\Http\Requests;



class PostsController extends Controller
{
    //
  public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index','show']);
  }

    public function index(){


        $posts = Post::latest()->get();
        return view('posts.index',compact('posts'));
    }

    public function show($id){

        $post = Post::find($id);
        return view('posts.show',compact('post'));
    }

    public function create(){
        return view('posts.create');
    }

   public function store(){
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required'

        ]);

    Post::create([
      'title' => request('title'),
      'body' => request('body'),
      'user_id' => auth()->id()
      ]);


    // $post = new Post;
    // $post->user_id = auth()->id()
    // $post->title = request('title');
    // $post->body = request('body');


    // $post->save();

    return redirect('/');

   }
}
```

here is the post model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['title','body','user_id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }



}
```

user model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the result of  `dd($post->user)`?

Comment: the result is: User {#179 ▼
  #fillable: array:3 [▶]
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:7 [▶]
  #original: array:7 [▶]
  #relations: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}

Comment: The error is in this line `{{ $post->user->name }}`? Or is pointing to another line?

Comment: Have you tried just using `$post->created_at` in the view instead of `$post->created_at->toFormattedDateString()`

Comment: @Laerte created_at is already working and data is retrived from post table, the problem only in line $post->user->name when i try to value from user table

Comment: It's odd that $post->user exists, but $post->user->name seems to be calling a null user.

Comment: On which line no. you facing this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to get property of non-object - Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469542/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-laravel-5)

Answer (score 1):

As you have said, you are getting this error while accessing `user`'s property through `post`. That means your `$post->user` is `null` or its not an `object` but `array`(which has less possibility).

The higher possibility is `null` issue. Have you checked it? I would prefer you use `{{$post->user->name ?? ''}}`(supported only in php 7) while showing user's name in view. Which means if `$post->user->name` is not set then show nothing.

Check if `$post->user` is `null` or not. If it is `null` for any `post` then the question is, why `$post->user` can be `null`? What are the possible causes?

**Possible Causes of `$post->user` to be null are:**

1. Relation is not built correctly. Make sure your `posts` table has a `user_id` column as your relationship is defined.
2. In `posts` table the `user_id` is nullable and for for that certain post `user_id` is null.
3. The `user_id` of that post is linked to a non-exist `user`. And this can be restrict using foreign constrain.