# Echo value in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

How can I get the value 'name' under 'rekenplichtige' in my Blade template? If I do this: `{{ $vestiging->rekenplichtige->name }}` I get the following error: ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object

That syntax is working to get the 'naam' under 'gemeente'. I have no idea about what's going wrong.

[image]

Comment: are you under php7?

Comment: yes version 7.1

Comment: this is explained in several posts here on stackoverflow

Comment: So it is a PHP problem? What search query do I have to do?

Comment: search on google for "php7 Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to get property of non-object - Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469542/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-laravel-5)

Answer (score 3):

```
 {{ $vestiging->rekenplichtige}}
```

since "name" inside an  array, you should array notation to get  name. Like below

```
{{ $vestiging->rekenplichtige['name'] }}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ $vestiging->rekenplichtige()->first()->name }}
```

This is working.