# Laravel array instead of collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections

In my Laravel application, I have this model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Division extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
               'name','company_id', 'location_id'
               ];

    protected $casts = [
                'name' => 'string',
                'company_id' => 'integer',
                'location_id' => 'integer'
                ];

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }

    public function location()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
    }

}
```

`$division->company` returns a collection

`$division->location` returns an array

Why this two relations has different results? (Sorry for bad formating....)

Comment: Can you show us the code where you call `location` relationship?

Comment: Both must return an object and not a collection or an array.

Comment: @foreach($companyDivisions as $division)
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>{{$division->name}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{$division->location->name}}</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            @endforeach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've just shown in the comments (and then edited), you're using it with `get()`. That's why you're getting a collection and not an object.

`$division->company` returns an object. Then you're running another query with `$division->company->anotherRelationship()->get()` which returns a collection of related objects.

Comment: Sorry, still not understand. In my opinion, I'm doing the same in both cases. $division->company->name shows the name of the company
$division->location['name'] shows the name of the location
$division->location->name give an error (Trying to get property of non-object)

Comment: @Peter before that you've shown something like `$division->company->anotherRelationship()->get()` in the comment. `Trying to get property of non-object` is a whole different error and you get it because the division is not associated with any company, so you get `null` instead of a `Company` object.

Comment: But why `$division->location['name']` shows the name and `$division->location->name` gives an error?

Comment: @Peter because it's `null`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't change anything but now it's working. It's really strange for me...

Comment: I found another article about it. But no solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48558412/8833437