# How to show records from two different tables in same view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, logic

I am here stuck in this issue:
The issue is i want to load the 2 column values from two different tables in same view and view in which i want to show the values is already having controller method: 
I will explain you with my code:

My controller method:

```
                   public function pageListHere()
   {
                   $list = PageList::all();
                   return view('page-list',compact('list'));
}
```

this is my method using `PageList` model table name is (`page_master`).

And my view is:

```
            @foreach($list as $key => $value)
            <tr>
            <input type="hidden" id="rwid" value="{{$value->id}}"/><td></td>
            <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Tolltip">{{$value->page_name}}</p></td>
            <td>  <a href="" class="pglst-lnk">  {{$value->page_url}</a</td>
           <td>
```

Now here i want to add two more values in blade template like `{{$value->coupon_count}}` and `{{$value->total sum}}`
But these two values are in different tables
How i can get these two values from  different tables while i am having same views and i have already define controller method:

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

```
    class PageList extends Model
     {
     protected $table = 'page_master';

    protected $appends = ['page_particulars','page_coupon'];

    protected $fillable = ['business_id', 'page_url', 'page_name'];

   public function getpageParticularsAttribute(){


  }
public function getpageCouponAttribute(){

      }
  }

              class PageCoupon extends Model
               {
             protected $table = 'page_coupon';

         protected $fillable = ['page_id','code','is_ordered','user_limit'];

       }
```

and 2nd model is:

```
               class Sale extends Model
               {
                protected $table = 'page_particulars';

protected $fillable = ['user_id','product_asin','page_expiry_date','market_place','promo_title','regular_price','promo_price','company_logo','coupon_file','email_from','email_subject','facebook_link','twitter_link','website_link','email_body'];
```

}

Comment: can you explain the relation between the two tables .. I can help you if you give more information

Answer (score 1):

You can either add a relation to the other table 
In your Model add

```
public function particulars()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Sale','page_id');
}

and use 

$value->particulars->regular_price;
```

or you can use Eloquent append to add new values to the same model

In your Model add

```
  protected $appends = ['coupon_count','total_sum']
```

and a function to get the attribute

```
  public function getCouponCountAttribute(){
     //fetch from other table and return here for example
     return Coupon::where('page_id',$this->id)->count();
  }
  public function getTotalSumAttribute(){
     //fetch from other table and return here
  }
```

Comment: how i can append new values to same model! can you show me

Comment: I need more information on how you get the values to explain clearly ..

Comment: I have added in my model with your answer please see

Comment: yes inside the function you can query for the correct value .. I've updated the answer with a simple example

Comment: can you please tell me how the coupons are stored and how you calculate the totalsum value (with the tables the values are stored in )

Comment: $this->id in query ( here id where coming from) i did not use these append so i am asking you ...

Comment: you said you need values from other table  ..please tell me the other table names and the model

Comment: The values i want from sale model is ( code ) and PageCoupon model is(coupon_count)

Comment: each page has a record in page_particulars table?

Comment: yes each page has record in page_particulars tables

Comment: and you have a page_id column in page_particulars right if so you could have used a simple has one relationship instead

Comment: when i use <p>{{$value->particulars->coupon_count}}</p>

Comment: it says  Trying to get property 'coupon_count' of non-object

Comment: can u tell me what error is that we are close to solution

Comment: actually I'm confused .. how do you get the coupon code based on a page .. just tell me in words .. no need of code

Comment: i just want to get the values from page_particulars tables and that coupon_count ( right now i have hard coded the value if this lets suppse its 10) and i just want to load it in my view like {{$value->particulars->coupon_count}} and this give me error trying to get property of non object

Comment: Its like 15 /20 in my view.. my field name in my view is Coupon Claimed and i want to show value 15 / 20 here (15) come from page_coupon table tables and 20 come from page_particulars tables

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469542/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-laravel-5/32469779?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: look at this link it posted something relevant to me i think issue is somewhere {{$value->particulars->regular_price}} it now allowing -> sign