# How to show current login user to the page laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and after many searches online, i can't figure out how to display curent login user to a page.

Here what I try

My controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    public function show($alias)
        {
          $alias = Node::where('alias', $alias)->first();
          $session = Auth::id();
          //$alias = Node::findOrFail($id);
          return view('front.blog.showblog', compact('alias', 'session'));
        }
```

in my page I call it like this `{{ $session }}`

Comment: What this prints `{{ $session }}` ?

Comment: i want to show id of $session that i call from controller

Comment: Why you are passing Auth id from controller you can easily get it on your view file by Auth::id()

Comment: try to post your login controller. If you didn't declare a new auth guard and Auth::user() returns null. then you are not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

There are Facade and Helper Functions:

Try this one: (**Facade**)

```
$session = \Auth::user()->id;
```

Or this: (**Helper**)

```
auth()->user()->id ;
```

Comment: i try two of them it showing "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Comment: Check the return type what its returning is it object or array.

Comment: @jazulyaja check your issue here this link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469542/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-laravel-5

Comment: First Check what are you getting in ```Auth::user()```.

Answer (score 0):

`Auth::guard('web')->user();` This will return all user data of logged in user.

`Auth::guard('web')->id();` This will return only user id;

Comment: it show me "Call to a member function id() on null"

Comment: I guess its ```Auth::guard('web')->user()->id```; Id is property not function.

Comment: `guard()` is for Accessing Specific Guard Instances