# How to extract data from foreign keys in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relational-database

I'm new at Laravel and not good with syntax. I want to see the values of another table through the foreign key(id of that table).

https://ibb.co/pXRFRHn You can see in this picture I get ids under user & class. I want the titles associated with these ids.

I have tables sections, users and a class. I use class_id & user_id as the foreign key in the section table. When I try to show data, I see the id, but I want the name & other fields extracted from that id.

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
$sections = Section::all();
$classs = Classs::all();
$users = User::all();

return view('sections.index')->with('sections', $sections)->with('classs', $classs)->with('users', $users);
}
```

**Blade/View**

```
<div class="box">
<div class="box-header">
    <h3 class="box-title">All Sections</h3>
</div>
<div class="box-body">
    <table class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Modify</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($sections as $cat)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$cat->title}}</td>
                <td>{{$cat->class_id}}</td>
                <td>{{$cat->user_id}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-info" data-mytitle="{{$cat->title}}"
                            data-myclassid="{{$cat->class_id}}" data-myuserid="{{$cat->user_id}}"
                            data-catid={{$cat->id}} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit">Edit
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" data-catid={{$cat->id}} data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#delete">Delete
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Specifically...

```
<td>{{$cat->class_id}}</td>
```

From this, I get the class id, but I want its name also.

```
{{$cat->(class_id)->name}}"
```

However, it didn't work.
I have edited Models

```
 class Classs extends Model
{
//
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'title',

];

public function section()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Section');

}}
```

**Section Model**

```
class Section extends Model
{
//
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'title',
    'class_id',
    'user_id',

];


public function classs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Classs');
}}
```

Comment: $section->class() or $class->section()

Comment: And ofcourse forget IE or Edge ;)

Comment: what are u asking please explain .

Comment: that's my question too you can check, I didn't get proper answers on it.

Comment: @AbdulRehman if you didn't like the answers you got on your other question you shouldn't have accepted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me... a bit long but simple

```
{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('class')->where('id',$cat->class_id)->value('name')}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`{{$cat->(class_id)->name}}`

try

`{{$cat->classs->name}}`

You are accessing the foreign key in the sections table with `$cat->(class_id)`, which works. But now you want to query the relationship via its dynamic properties, which requires `$cat->classs->"any properties of classs"`.

Comment: I just changed it and it gives this error.I don't know which column is this talking about.




SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'classses.section_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `classses` where `classses`.`section_id` = 2 and `classses`.`section_id` is not null) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\jurs1\resources\views\sections\index.blade.php)

Comment: Sorry, I did not check carefully enough. I believe your data model is not correct. The foreign key must be defined in the "belongsTo" Model/Table. So, if the relations in the database tables are correct, then just swap "belongsTo" and "hasMany" in your models. And then see my previous answer.

Comment: "Trying to get property 'title' of non-object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469542/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-laravel-5/32469779

same issue but can't understand if you can help me please

Comment: Replace 'return view('sections.index')->with ...' with 'return view('sections.index', compact('sections', 'classs', 'users'));'

Answer (score 0):

try `$section->classs`, it should be an array because the relation is hasMany and maybe you should create a filter to get the right id.

Eloquent has another way to get relationship with SQL where clause and others.

`$section->classs()->where('title', 'foo')->first();`

---

Little tips and if you want to try it.

When returning the view, you can with `->with()` method in Laravel, use compact php function for a clear call and code.

```
return view('sections.index')->with(compact('sections', 'classs', 'users'));
```

Comment: "Property [classs] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\jurs1\resources\views\sections\index.blade.php)"

Comment: Check if the $section var is instead $cat in your view. If you are in the loop it is. If not, try `{{dd($section)}}` or `{{dd($section->classs)}}` to check the current value of your var.

Comment: where do I have to check this $section in controller or blade ?

Comment: Curlybraces  are only available in blade template, so if you want to do debug in blade you use the code in my comment above. You can also use the laravel function `dd($yourVariableName)` in your controller

Comment: I'm so sorry i m so bad at it .. Can you please change my code as u are asking and tell me what these functions are