# Trying to get property 'service_type' of non-object in laravel it is not an array

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting error `Trying to get property 'service_type' of non-object` in laravel 
controller

```
$services= Service::pluck('service_type', 'service_id');
return view('package', compact('services'));
```

View:

```
<select class="form-control" name="service_type" id="service_type" data-parsley-required="true">
  @foreach ($services as $service )
      <option value="{{ $service->service_id }}">{{ $service->service_type }}</option>
  @endforeach 
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to get property of non-object - Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469542/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-laravel-5)

Comment: it should be `<option value="{{ $service['service_id'] }}">{{ $service['service_type'] }}</option>` i guess

Comment: i am getting this error Trying to get property 'service_id' of non-object

Comment: @chaitra i've updated my comment

Comment: Illegal string offset 'service_id'

Comment: @chaitra try this in you controller `$services= Service::pluck('service_type', 'service_id')->toArray();`

Comment: getting same error

Comment: i am trying to fetch from service table in package controller in package view am i doing correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pluck` is not working as expected. Tested with several process and it does not work. use `select` with `get` or simply `get`.

```
$services= Service::get(['service_type', 'service_id']);
$services= Service::select('service_type', 'service_id')->get(); 
//use anyone from the above
```

And in view:

```
@foreach ($services as $service )
    <option value="{{ $service->service_id }}">{{ $service->service_type }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: do you know how to get Distinct value in this

Comment: i have the mysql how to impliment to this $services= Service::SELECT DISTINCT(( 'service_type', 'service_id' ) FROM services ORDER BY 'service_type' DESC)->get();

Comment: you can use `distinct()` or `groupBy`

Comment: but i am getting error syntax error, unexpected 'DISTINCT' (T_STRING)

Comment: assuming you want distinct `service_id`. So do like `$services= Service::distinct('service_id')->get(['service_type', 'service_id']);`

Comment: $services = Service::select('select service_type,service_id from services GROUP BY service_type DESC')->get();  is this correct i want this type group by

Comment: do it in eloquent way. `$services= Service::select('service_type', 'service_id')->groupBy('service_type')->get();`

Comment: it is showing SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'first_prj.services.service_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `service_type`, `service_id` from `services` group by `service_type`)

Comment: thats mysql version error. you can find solution for this here in so.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$services` variable is not an object, hence you can access it's properties with object notation `->`. To display them, alter your view to this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="service_type" id="service_type" data-parsley-required="true">
  @foreach ($services as $service )
      <option value="{{ $service['service_id'] }}">{{ $service['service_type'] }}</option>
  @endforeach 
</select>
```