# How to solve Trying to get property of non-object in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm a beginner web developer
I'm trying to write a condition that will be fulfilled depending on what data the user will send
Condition if fulfilled by one hundred percent
But the condition else produces an error with the following text

Trying to get property 'unique_id' of non-object

If someone have info how to solv this problem I will be grateful

This is my code from controller

```
public function checkRestorePassword(Request $request)
{
    $result['success'] = false;

    $rules = [
        'unique_id' => 'required',
    ];
    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
    if (empty($validation))
    {
        $result['error'] = "Enter the code that was sent to you by mail.";
        return response()->json($result, 422);
    }
    $user = User::where('unique_id', $request->uniqueId)->first();
    if ($user->unique_id === $request->uniqueId)
    {
        $result['success'] = 'Access to your personal account successfully restored. Please change your password.';
        return response()->json($result, 200);
    }
    else
    {
        $result['success'] = false;
        return response()->json($result, 422);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can check this solution , i think it will help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469542/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-laravel-5

Comment: I think your `$user` might be `null` hence it can not find `unique_id` property inside it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to get property of non-object - Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469542/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-laravel-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because `$user` is returning `null`.

so do this

```php
if (!is_null($user) && $user->unique_id === $request->uniqueId)
```