# Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\preecom\resources\views\layouts\slider.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to add layouts file with my content

i am getting error non object please resolve it.

My layout file code

```
<!-- Banner -->

@php
 $slider = DB::table('products')
                    ->join('brands','products.brand_id','brands.id')
                    ->select('products.*','brands.brand_name')
                    ->where('main_slider',1)->orderBy('id','DESC')->first();



@endphp
<div class="banner">
    <div class="banner_background" style="background-image:url({{ asset('public/frontend/images/banner_background.jpg')}})"></div>
    <div class="container fill_height">
        <div class="row fill_height">
            <div class="banner_product_image"><img src="{{ asset( $slider->image_one  )}}" alt="" style="height: 450px;" ></div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 offset-lg-4 fill_height">
                <div class="banner_content">
                    <h1 class="banner_text">{{ $slider->product_name }}</h1>
                    <div class="banner_price">
                @if($slider->discount_price == NULL)
               <h2> ${{ $slider->selling_price }} </h2>
                @else
             <span>${{ $slider->selling_price }}</span>${{ $slider->discount_price }}
                @endif




                    </div>
                    <div class="banner_product_name">{{ $slider->brand_name }}</div>
                    <div class="button banner_button"><a href="#">Shop Now</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting this error in return 
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\preecom\resources\views\layouts\slider.blade.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to get property of non-object - Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469542/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-laravel-5)

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: The only way this error could happen in your case is that ```$slider``` is null. Check this variable before your first div by doing: ```@dd($slider)```, this will dump and die the variable so you can see its content

Comment: if $slider is null how do i fix it kindly tell me

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get a property from a variable which should be an object but is not.
Be sure that $slider is not null or false.

Comment: $slider is not null