# Auth::user()->name is not working in package view in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have developed a package for Laravel in which I'm trying to fetch the logged in user name but it is giving error.
package is currently in the vendor folder

**error**

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object
```

How I can get current logged in user name?

Comment: Please show the code that causes this error.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469542/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-laravel-5

Comment: @Severin {{Auth::user()->name}} this is code. it is in package's views

Comment: The error is telling you that `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`, meaning the object you are calling `->name` on does not exist. So it seems that there is no authenticated user at this point. If you do `dd(Auth::user());` you will likely get `null`

Please update the question with the full code that errors, so we can help you.

Comment: yeah i understand that but currently user is logged in. issue is i am calling user() on auth in package which i have developed. and Auth doesn't work directly in package

Comment: please check `Auth::user()` in your Laravel application level .out of your package

Comment: @TirdadAbbasi where i will find this level?

Comment: I write a new answer. please check this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to add web middleware in your route like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('/', ['uses'=>'Admin@index']);
    });
});
```

Comment: Nopw i need to add one more guard in middlware what should i do ?

Comment: you can add more middleware in middleware array like this  `['web', 'admin']`

Comment: but second middleware is not available in package's routes. it is available in default project routes but not in package's routes

Comment: I think it's will work. did you check? do you have any error?

Comment: yes i did. only one guard work at a time. web or auth:customer

Comment: in my example, I added other middleware in another route group please try that method

Comment: I checked that as i told you it will execute guard which comes later . but if i change route for both guards then it work fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220759/discussion-between-tirdad-abbasi-and-web-pakistan).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
{{auth()->user()->name}}
```

instead of what you are using currently.