# i want to hide html code when product is_featured column status all equal to zero using laravel

Tags: laravel

i am trying to hide html code by if condition when all product featured is zero, html code should not be shown in front page please help me how can i do that ?

controller

```
public  function index()
{



$data = [

    'products' => Product::with('productColorGallary')->where('is_featured', 1)->first(),
   
      ];

   return view('home', $data);
 }
```

**html view**

```
   @if($products->is_featured  == 0)
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="new-wall-image">
            <img src="{{config('wall_master_furishing.file_url').$products->productColorGallary->featured_image}}" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="new-wall-descp">
            <h2 class="theme-title">New Walls
            </h2>
            <p>{!!$products->description!!}</p>
            <a class="blue-btn-a" href="#">Read More
              <i class="fa fa-angle-right">
              </i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        @endif
```

Comment: ErrorException
Trying to get property 'is_featured' of non-object (View: /home/zubair/htdocs/wallmasterfurnishing.com/web/resources/views/home.blade.php)

Comment: try this `firstOrFail()` like `Product::with('productColorGallary')->where('is_featured', 1)->firstOrFail()`

Comment: is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469542/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-laravel-5 >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting your products in your database with is_featured = 1. It means that your if condition in your blade will be always false.

Plus, are you trying to get all products or just one ?
If it's many, then :

Your controller

```php
public  function index()
{
   $products = Product::with('productColorGallary')->get();
   return view('home', compact('products');
 }
```

and your blade

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    @if($product->is_featured  == 0)
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="new-wall-image">
            <img src="{{config('wall_master_furishing.file_url').$product->productColorGallary->featured_image}}" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="new-wall-descp">
            <h2 class="theme-title">New Walls
            </h2>
            <p>{!!$products->description!!}</p>
            <a class="blue-btn-a" href="#">Read More
              <i class="fa fa-angle-right">
              </i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
    @else
      SOMETHING HERE IF PRODUCT IS FEATURED
    @endif
     SOMETHING HERE COMMONS TO BOTH FEATURED AND NOT FEATURED

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Products is an array key, so you can use like $data['products'] etc..
But if you create a collection/object like the following should be work:

```php
public  function index()
{
   // first will return the first matched item from db 
   // and you will get only is_featured = 1
   $products = Product::with('productColorGallary')->where('is_featured', 1)->first();
   return view('home', compact('products');
 }
```

Comment: Trying to get property 'is_featured' of non-object (View: /home/zubair/htdocs/wallmasterfurnishing.com/web/resources/views/home.blade.php)

Comment: before return you should write dd($product); and probably you will see that is featured: 1 and this condition ```@if($products->is_featured  == 0)``` won't  work. However ```@if featured  == 0 @else // when feature is 1 or anything else @endif``` should work.