# Trying to get property 'point' of non-object

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with get value of object ,I tried many posts here in stackoverflow like this : [Trying to get property of non-object - Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469542/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-laravel-5) but it isn't solved.

I have this controller method :

```
public function user_team($id)
    {
        $week = Week::where('status','active')->first();
        $week_id = $week->id;
        $team = Team::where('user_id',$id)->with('userteams')->get();
        
        foreach ($team[0]->userteams as $userteam) {
            $userteam->surname = $userteam->Club->surname;
            $userteam->price = $userteam->Club->price;
            $points = Userpoint::where('club_id',$userteam->club_id)->where('week_id',$week_id)->where('user_id',$id)->first();
            $point =  $points->point;
            $userteam->point = $point;
            unset($userteam->Club);
        }
        return $team;
    }
```

teams return this in post man :

```
[
  {
    "id": 40,
    "team_name": "",
    "season_id": 1,
    "week_id": 2,
    "user_id": 223269719,
    "created_at": "2021-07-30T13:34:44.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-07-30T13:34:44.000000Z",
    "userteams": [
      {
        "id": 277,
        "team_id": 40,
        "club_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2021-07-30T13:34:44.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-07-30T13:34:44.000000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 278,
        "team_id": 40,
        "club_id": 21,
        "created_at": "2021-07-30T13:34:44.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-08-01T10:37:03.000000Z"
      },
```

and $points->point is return a value : 9

but when I try

```
$point =  $points->point
```

it give me error : `Trying to get property 'point' of non-object`

Comment: where you use  `point =  $points->point `  means in the view or else

Comment: @Pradeep it is shown in first code after `$points = Userpoint::where('club_id',$userteam->club_id)->where('week_id',$week_id)->where('user_id',$id)->first();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it :
public function user_team($id)
{
$week = Week::where('status','active')->first();

```
    $week_id = $week->id;
    $team = Team::where('user_id',$id)->with('userteams')->first();
    
    foreach ($team->userteams as $userteam) {
        $userteam->surname = $userteam->Club->surname;
        $userteam->price = $userteam->Club->price;

        $points = $userteam->Club->userpoints;
        if(isset($oiints)){
         foreach ($points as $point) {
            
           if($point->user_id == $id){
               $userteam->point = $point->point;
           }
        }
        }else{
            $userteam->point = 0;
        }
        
        unset($userteam->Club->userpoints);
        unset($userteam->Club);

    }
    return $team;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($team[0]->userteams as $key => $userteam) {
        $userteam->surname = $userteam->Club->surname;
        $userteam->price = $userteam->Club->price;
        $points = Userpoint::where('club_id',$userteam->club_id)->where('week_id',$week_id)->where('user_id',$id)->first();
        $team[0]->userteams[$key]['point'] =  $points->point;
        unset($userteam->Club);
    }
```

There i updated it, can you try again with this code

Comment: I get this error `Indirect modification of overloaded element of App\Models\Team has no effect`